# Hide ios 8 sidebar swift?

Tags: swift, sidebar

im currently using the amazing open source library https://github.com/evnaz/ENSwiftSideMenu for my application navigation sidebar. However, I created an login page for the project, but couldn't figure out an way to hide the sidebar in my login page, can anyone help me?

my view controller (where will guide the user to login page if login does not login )

```
 import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
    if currentUser != nil {
        NSLog("CurrentUser:", currentUser.username)
        // Do stuff with the user
    } else {
        // Show the signup or login screen
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showLogin", sender: self)
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func logout(sender: AnyObject) {
    PFUser.logOut()
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showLogin", sender: self)

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "showLogin") {
        // pass data to next view
        segue.destinationViewController.sideMenuController()?.sideMenu?.hideSideMenu()
        //sideMenuController()?.sideMenu?.hideSideMenu()
    }
}
```

}

my login page:

```
import UIKit

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var usernameField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!
@IBAction func loginButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    var username = String (self.usernameField.text .stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet()))
    var password = String (self.passwordField.text .stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet()))

    if username.isEmpty || password.isEmpty{
        let alert = UIAlertView()
        alert.title = "Oops"
        alert.message = "Please make sure you enter all the field"
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("Okay")
        alert.show()

    }
    else {
        PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(username, password:password) {
            (user: PFUser!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if user != nil {
                // Do stuff after successful login.
                self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
            } else {
                // The login failed. Check error to see why.
                let alert = UIAlertView()
                alert.title = "Oops"
                alert.message = error.userInfo!["error"] as NSString
                alert.addButtonWithTitle("Okay")
                alert.show()
            }
        }
    }

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    //self.sideMenuController()?.sideMenu?.hideSideMenu()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: There seem to be a extension method that you can call?            toggleSideMenuView() its declared here https://github.com/evnaz/ENSwiftSideMenu/blob/master/Library/ENSideMenu.swift

Comment: do i leave add the method on my login controller?

Comment: I don't know what your code look like so its really hard to tell.

Comment: i have add the pages i think there might be a problem. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to call hideSideMenuView() function in your view controller. It is view controller's extension public function. Also there are showSideMenuView() and toggleSideMenuView() functions.